# Will my application benefit from launch modes and intent flags?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I have written a simple Sudoku solving app that looks like this: [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4018313/Screenshot_2013-08-16-02-02-22.png)

When you press a button, a keypad will show up that lets you select what number to asign to that button. The typical use case is probably that the user opens the app then assigns all the numbers that make up the sudoku puzzle they want to solve and then press the solve button.

From my understanding of Android this will create a task that is made up of a lot of main and keypad activities (the keypad is an activity as a dialog). Every time you assign a new number you will put a keypad activity on top of the main one when the keypad appears. Then when you have selected a number and the keypad dissappears you will put another main activity on top of the keypad activity.

Is this how it works out that you get a lot of activitys that you dont really need? Have I misunderstood this thing?

Should I use launch modes and intent flags to reuse the same main activty and keypad over and over again or is it fine to just use the standard version?

Comment: Popping android keyboard is a feature/service handled by Android system itself. It will not use an activity to show over your activity.

Comment: Personally I'd just put 9 numbered buttons along the bottom of the screen for portrait or to the side of the screen for landscape. It would save a popup keypad appearing and disappearing and require less code.

Comment: Yes, I did that but then I changed to this cuz I wanted to try how to do it. I'm really new at developing for android so I just try a bunch of stuff to learn.

Waqas: It's not the android keyboard it's a keypad dialog, look at the screenshot.

Comment: @Alex : Fine. I appreciate you're just trying different ideas but remember UX means designing apps which are most accessible and easiest to use by the end user. Also the fact you're concerned about Activities coming and going just suggested to me it would be a cleaner solution to have everything on-screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your problem, you can use the `Intent Flag` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. If the `Activity` is already on the stack then it will, as it says, bring it to the top of the stack so you don't have multiple instances of it.

Something like

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KeypadActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
 startActivity(i);
```

You can find all available `Flags` [Here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Also, calling `finish()` on say the keypad `Activity` when you are done with it and go to the next one will take it off of the stack.

[Google navigation presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwGHJJYBs0Q)

Comment: The thing is that the keypad calls finish() in order to disappear. Will this delete the keypad activity drom the top of the task? There is not really a problem. I just read about it and this is how I interpreted it.

Comment: Yes, calling `finish()` will remove it from the stack. Just a second and I will edit with a link to a Google presentation about handling the stack and navigation...

Comment: Added link. Very helpful

Comment: Ok, so the the same main activity(the activity with the sudoku board) will me used every time? Is there a way to create a keypad that will be reused and by doing so increase performance? It's lagging a little bit when the keypad opens.

Comment: If you want to use a custom layout for it then I would create the keypad `Activity` and re-use it as in my suggestion or you could create a fragment dialog possibly that would hold the `layout`. I'm not sure what the lag is from without knowing more but this shouldn't give you a problem.